# How to prevent a node from listing programmatically?

Tags: 6, users

How can I prevent a node from listing, programmatically? I want to select node by nid. Beacause of some reasons, I don't want to use `hook_node_grants()` and `hook_node_access_records()`

I tried to change the `_node_access_where_sql()` function in the core which creates where clause for use in fetching node listings but *$node* or *$nid* is not passed to the function so I can't select node by *nid*

Comment: Where do you want to stop this content being listed?  In the standard content listing?  It's a REALLY REALLY bad idea to be hacking core...

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply unpublishing the node with Rules? Rules will allow you to programmatically unpublish content based on a variety of factors. Once unpublished, Drupal will not list the node in content with the exception of Views that are not set to only display published content.

What are you using to determine which nodes should be processed by your code?